Angular Signals for large State Management
Evaluating architecture for a rework of our application in modern Angular, I find Signals to be great candidates for state management.
However, our application is quite large, and playing with some ideas, I am finding some pitfalls.

The first design wraps a custom AppState in a Signal

@Injectable()
export class AppStateService {
    private appState = signal(new AppState());


    public getState() {
        return this.appState.asReadonly();
    }

    public setForm(form: FormGroup) {
        this.appState.update(state => {
            state.form = form;
            return state;
        })
    }

    public addError(error: AppError) {
        this.appState.update(state => {
            state.errors.push(error)
            return state;
        })
    }
}

But I understand this is not efficient as changing one part of the state will re-evaluate every dependent code.

With a second design, I investigated @ngrx/signals, thinking the concept of 'fine-grained reactivity' and nested/deep signals would solve this issue:

export const AppStore = signalStore(
    withState(initialAppState),
    withMethods((store) => ({
        addError: (error: AppError): void => {
            patchState(store, (state) => ({ errors: [...state.errors, error] }));
        },
        setForm: (form: FormGroup): void => {
            patchState(store, (state) => ({ form: form }));
        },
        debug: (): any => {
            const state = store.form().getRawValue(); // Trying a "partial" state use
            return state;
        },
    })),
);

But in this second example, if I use the debug() function in the code, I noticed at least two issues:

If I call the method twice in the template, it is called twice. I know it is not ideal and I could solve this with template variables, but I was still expecting some kind of memoization?
My biggest complain; even with this partial use, which only uses the nested signal form, if I push a value in errors, this method is re-evaluated, while we know nothing has changed in form

Is there a better way for state management? Should I just give up with centralized state management and split in different states by concern? I worry that this might lead to spaghetti code, when I will need one sub-state change to have side-effects on others. And I don't see the value of @ngrx/signals over a single big state for performance/reactivity.

Try this: https://ngrx.io/guide/signals/signal-store

simillar to old ngrx selectors form = computed(() => store.form()); value = computed(() =>  form().getRowValue()) would still reexecute "form" computation in your case, but "value" would be the old one, because the form didn't change. It should fix the concept problems you described, but do not use such thing for forms, as form object is being mutated and it just never changes

Curiosity: why you need store the whole formGroup else the formGroup.value? why not set the value in ngOnDestroy?

Yes, storing form is likely a bad example. Here my concern was mostly that modifying one attribute has side-effect to other unrelated attributes
